# What does prepareserializer from protobuf-net do?

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

I assume it looks at your model and somehow gets things ready, so that your first few serializations aren't slowed. What if my messaging model has a message class with child classes? Does putting my parent class in the type argument prepare all the children too?

Comment: Oh, I should also note: if you want the absolute minimal spin-up, you can pre-compile the serializers to an assembly (dll), and reference that in your main project...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(this answer assumes protobuf-net v2)

If you mean `Serializer.PrepareSerializer<T>()`, then it will certainly *inspect* all the child-types, so the type-model will be prepared for them (meaning: it will figure out what fields/properties etc need serializing). It will pre-compile (i.e. IL-emit) the code for the *parent* class, but (looking at the code) not specifically for the derived types. If unattended, the derived types will compile themselves when first needed. I think! I can do a thorough check if you really want.

However, if you use `RuntimeTypeModel.Default.CompileInPlace()`, it builds the entire model - everything known is prepared. Of course, that then leaves the dilemma of having to tell the model about them first ;p

I'll double check to see at what point the sub-type serializers are prepared, just to be sure. It might indeed make sense to cascade them.

---

Update:

it looks like it does indeed cascade to *derived* types, but not to the *parent* type (if any):

```
    [Test]
    public void CheckTypeSpecificCompileInPlaceCascadesToBaseAndChildTypes()
    {
        var model = TypeModel.Create();
        model[typeof(B)].CompileInPlace();

        Assert.IsTrue(model.IsPrepared(typeof(D)), "D"); // sub-sub-type
        Assert.IsTrue(model.IsPrepared(typeof(C)), "C"); // sub-type
        Assert.IsTrue(model.IsPrepared(typeof(B)), "B"); // self
        Assert.IsTrue(model.IsPrepared(typeof(A)), "A"); // base-type
    }

    [Test]
    public void CheckGlobalCompileInPlaceCascadesToBaseAndChildTypes()
    {
        var model = TypeModel.Create();
        model.Add(typeof (B), true); // give the model a clue!
        model.CompileInPlace();

        Assert.IsTrue(model.IsPrepared(typeof(D)), "D"); // sub-sub-type
        Assert.IsTrue(model.IsPrepared(typeof(C)), "C"); // sub-type
        Assert.IsTrue(model.IsPrepared(typeof(B)), "B"); // self
        Assert.IsTrue(model.IsPrepared(typeof(A)), "A"); // base-type
    }
```

Here, the second test passes; the first test fails citing "A" - so the sub-types ("C" and "D") were fully compiled. Since the base type will still get compiled on demand, this is *probably* fine as-is, but I could probably make it tract to ancestor types if that would be useful.

(the `IsPrepared` method only exists in my local copy)

Comment: I was just curious as to what it did. My program isn't sensitive to the spin-up time. Thanks for getting back to me so soon.

Comment: @Carlos it just all the possible thinking it might need to do ahead of time; otherwise, it does it as it needs to (first time only).